# Pegar valor do atributo data- e aplicar como texto em outro elemento html

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, atributos

Eu possuo uma série de checkboxes em uma interface que já estão configurados para exibir/ocultar outros elementos da interface de forma condicional. Nesta mesma interface possuo um `div` definido para exibir mensagens para o usuário também de forma condicional dependendo do checkbox selecionado.

Fiz esse exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plan/q9sa4btr/) baseado em outro script, que usa .each na função pra verificar os inputs com determinada classe e "imprimir" o texto do label desses inputs em outro elemento, no caso um `<span>`

Acontece que na interface "final" os elementos checkbox e radio são customizados e utilizam a tag `<label>` para definir seus estilos, o que por sua vez, não me permite inserir textos nos elementos `<label>` e por isso não posso usar essa função...

Haveria outra maneira, mais simples e coerente de exibir mensagens condicionais extraídas talvez do atributo `data-`?

Aqui está o código mencionado no link do jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim existe. veja esse [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/433df396/).

Basta colocar, como você mesmo mencionou, `data-<elemento>` e utilizá-lo. Veja que no caso, foi usado `data-text` e para iterar sobre ele basta utilizar o elemento do jquery `$.data()` recuperando a tag `text` ou seja, `$.data("text")`.

Veja código HTML abaixo:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="money" class="paymethods cash">
<label data-text="cash from data" for="money">In Cash</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="card" class="paymethods ccard">
<label data-text="card from data" for="card">Credit Card</label>

<div class="messages">You have chosen to pay <span class="pay-method" data-cash="In cash" data-card="Credit Card" data-paymix="In cash & Credit Card"></span> for your order upon delivery</div>
```

Note que em cada `label` foi colocado um `data-text` com o valor a ser exibido no `$.foreach()` do código javascript.

A seguir, veja o código javascipt:

```
$(".paymethods").on("change", function(){
    var paymethods = [];
    $('.paymethods:checked').each(function(){        
        var payTypes = $(this).next().data("text");
        paymethods.push(payTypes);
    });
    $(".pay-method").html(paymethods.join(" & "));
})
```

Aqui manteve-se a solução apresentada, contudo, ao invés se se recuperar os valores de cada `label` utilizando `$.text()`, utiliza-se `$.data("text")`.

Comment: Isso não é uma resposta amigo, você deve apresentar o seu código e explicar o porque para ensinar aquele que fez a pergunta.

Comment: O código está aí :)

Comment: agora melhorou :)

Comment: Obrigado, isso soluciona a questão de não poder usar textos nos elementos `<label>`, de fato usar `$.data("text")` faz muito sentido. Agora eu estava pensando se não haveria uma função ainda mais enxuta para simplesmente "alternar" entre os diferentes atributos `data-` de um elemento e exibí-los neste mesmo elemento. Veja por favor a tag `<span>` com os atributos `data-`definidos. Nesta solução aqui https://jsfiddle.net/plan/z0n1moyu/ tem um approach bem grosseiro para verificar se os checkboxes estão marcados e então "alternar" os valores...

Comment: Achei a solução que utiliza o `$.foreach()` bastante elegante. Ela é simples e resolve o problema de forma clara e rápida :).

Comment: @EduardoFernandes boa resposta, `+1` . Semanticamente talvez faça mais sentido usar o `.map()`. Apenas sugestão: https://jsfiddle.net/433df396/2/

Answer (score 2):

Engraçado, eu costumo pegar data-attributes de outra forma. Acho que existem diversas formas de se fazer essa ação. Fica então como alternativa. **Veja como eu faço:**

```js
$("select#teste").change(function(e) {

  //PEGANDO O DATA-ATTRIBUTE
  let data_id = $("select#teste option:selected").attr('data-id');
  //Pegando value
  let val = $("select#teste option:selected").val();
  //Pegando text
  let text = $("select#teste option:selected").text();

  alert("Vindo do data-atributte: " + data_id);
  alert("Vindo do value: " + val);
  alert("Vindo do text: " + text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="teste">
  <option value="Valor_1" data-id="1">Valor Text 1</option>
  <option value="Valor_2" data-id="2">Valor Text 2</option>
  <option value="Valor_3" data-id="3">Valor Text 3</option>
  <option value="Valor_4" data-id="4">Valor Text 4</option>
</select>
```